# How to prevent Swagger from following 302 Redirects?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

So I have an API in swagger that works properly. However, I want to disable it automatically following 302 redirect as I need the query params on the Location header of a 302. Is there any way how to do it in Swagger / Open API 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger UI and Swagger Editor [always follow redirects](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1569#issuecomment-390877095). To see 3xx responses, test the requests using non-browser tools such as `curl`. You can copy `curl` commands from Swagger UI.

```
curl https://httpbin.org/status/302 -i
```